# Why is fasting not permitted in the first 12 day of Sivan?

Tags: fast-days, shavuos, yahrtzeit

The Yahrzeit for my father falls on 7 Sivan. In the past it was always my custom to fast on 8 Sivan unless it was a Shabbat. Then I would fast on 9 Sivan.

This came up in discussion with my (Chabad) Rabbi.
He told me that it is forbidden to fast on the first 12 days of Sivan. Why is that?

Comment: 8 Sivan cannot fall on shabbat in our current calendar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

R Eli Mansour explains [here](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=1440)

> During the times of the Beth Hamikdash, those who were unable to bring
>   their sacrifices on the day of Shavuot itself – which in Israel is
>   celebrated only on the sixth of Sivan - were allowed to do so during
>   the six days following Shavuot, through the twelfth of Sivan

As such some don't say Tahanun in the week after Shavuot. The [Mishna Brura 131:36](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.131.36?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) for instance writes

> There are places that omit Tachnun for six days after Shavuot, because
>   the sacrifices of Shavuos have seven days of Tashlumin - compensation.

Similarly the Alter Rebbe of Chabad [writes](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/fasting-on-days-before-shavuos/) in his siddur

> **One may not fast from the first of Sivan until after Shavuos. [This
>   applies until, and including, the 12th of Sivan]**

while in the Shulchan HaRav, he permits fasting from the 9th.

It is very likely your Chabad rabbi refers to these rulings.

Comment: Indeed this is traditionally a Hasidic/Sefardic position, so it is consistent coming from a Chabad rabbi. The Rama on the other hand for Ashkenazim is clear that Tachanun restarts right away on 9 Sivan

Comment: @DoubleAA Although the prevalent custom in Israel, even for Ashkenazim, is to omit tachanun until after the twelfth. (The exception apparently being followers of the Chazon Ish who restart from the 8th - day after Isru Chag in Israel.)

Comment: @joelk like other things, many Israeli Ashkenazim took on various local Sefardi customs (eg. Morid haTal) for better or worse. It takes real dedication to your tradition to say Tachanun for 5 more days than everyone else. It's unfortunately not surprising that many Ashkenazim caved

Comment: For the incredibly reasonable prohibition of Kitniyot the Ashkenzi rabbis in Israel fight tooth and nail, but give 'em a newfangled obscure reason to skip Tachanun for a week and even they'll jump ship!

Comment: @mbloch Please pardon my chabadic ignorance. Isn't the "Alter Rebbe of Chabad" the Baal Hatania, who also authored the Shulchan Aruch Harav? How then would "the Alter Rebbe of Chabad" write in his siddur that One may not fast from the first of Sivan until after Shavuos. [This applies until, and including, the 12th of Sivan], 
while the Shulchan HaRav, who is one and the same with the "Alter Rebbe" permits fasting from the 9th of Sivan"?

Comment: @ribbis In his Siddur he generally adopted the more Kabbalistic/Sefardic practices. In his earlier Shulchan Arukh he generally codified the traditional Ashkenzi rulings

Comment: @DoubleAA :) It's more than just 5 days. Don't forget Pesach Sheni and Tishrei 24-29...

Comment: @JoelK shver zu zein an Ashkenazi. We have such tzaros...